# how to convert .dat file to .mat in Matlab

Tags: image, matlab

I have a .dat file which contains MRI images. i want to open this file in Matlab and convert it to .mat file which will contain "MrPort" and "Reco". Could anyone help me with this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the dat file into matlab, set `MrPort` and `Reco` variables and then save to mat file:

```
>> save('myMatFile.mat', 'MrPort', 'Reco' );
```